# MediaTek WiFi module stopped working in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, drivers, 20.04, wireless, kernel

Steps prior to the issue: Had my wireless headset connected to the laptop via USB port (idk if that makes any difference), powered off the system and went to bed.

Now my Wireless connection menu is gone from Settings.

My attempts to fix the issue:

- Tried using older kernels such as 5.17.0.
- Updating and upgrading apt and apt-get.

I have a very basic understanding of how Linux works and i have a few other solutions I've seen on here but unsuccessfully.

PC type: ASUS Laptop with Ryzen 5000 series CPU.
OS: Ubuntu 20.04

Kernel version: 5.17.1-051701-generic (i had to update it myself because my Bluetooth wasn't working but i left previous versions on the boot drive).

I have Windows 10 as a second OS installed. Hadn't launched that in days.

WiFi card:

```
lspci -nnk | grep -A2 0280

04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: MEDIATEK Corp. Device [14c3:7961]
    Subsystem: AzureWave Device [1a3b:4680]
    Kernel modules: mt7921e

    sudo lshw -class network
...Realtek Ethernet Controller
    *-network UNCLAIMED
           description: Network controller
           product: MEDIATEK Corp.
           vendor: MEDIATEK Corp.
           physical id: 0
           bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
           version: 00
           width: 64 bits
           clock: 33MHz
           capabilities: pciexpress msi pm cap_list
           configuration: latency=0
           resources: iomemory:fe0-fdf iomemory:fe0-fdf iomemory:fe0-fdf memory:fe20300000-fe203fffff memory:fe20400000-fe20403fff memory:fe20404000-fe20404fff
...another ethernet interface?
```

Is there a way to fix this? Please let me know if i can provide additional info here. Thank you.

UPD: I tried using NVIDIA driver metapackage instead of X.Org (in Software & Updates), it didn't help. During one of the restarts i saw the Wireless option come back to life but my system just froze and went unresponsive shortly after the boot. So i rebooted it and the WiFi is gone again. I have absolutely no idea what is happening.

Comment: Hello. How is kernel 5.17 older?

Comment: Hi David, i called it older because it's an earlier version than 5.17.1.

Comment: I don't think we have enough information here to help you. Some of the things you can do are: 1) Check your 'dmesg 'output, do you see any errors? 2) Do you see your wireless device using 'ip a'? If so, does iwconifg <wlan device> show anything helpful?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like switching to previous kernel version (5.13) helped? I'd appreciate if anyone with more knowledge could add to this to clarify what exactly happened here.

What i did:

Restarted my system and chose "Advanced options for Ubuntu".

Note to self: always have multiple kernel versions available.